# react-virtualized: scroll while mouse over header or locked left columns

Tags: react-virtualized

In the [multigrid demo](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/MultiGrid),  is there a way to enable scrolling while the mouse is over the headers or locked left columns (both sides of the ScrollSync)?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is pass scrollSyncParams.scrollTop and scrollSyncParams.onScroll to both top and bottom grids.